# Propagate kubernetes service labels to Prometheus with the usage of podMonitor

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I know that in Servicemonitor spec,we need to add [targetlabel](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/api.md#monitoring.coreos.com/v1.ServiceMonitor)s in order to propagate the service labels to Prometheus.

Is there any similar way to propagate the service labels to Prometheus but with the usage of a podMonitor? I can see that [podTargetLabels](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/api.md#monitoring.coreos.com/v1.PodMonitor) exist as an option but I think that it's not the same thing.